# mpm_winnt:notice and core:notice in Apache log. Is it ok?

Tags: php, apache

Well, my problem is that I have `500 Internal Server Error`, but I'm unable to figure out what it is. I switched to php.ini-development as php.ini, I turned on all error reporting I could, I created and set `error_log` file in php folder. But nothing is reported. My simplest in the world php file looks like this:

```
<?php
  ini_set('display_startup_errors',1); 
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(-1);
  echo "Hello";
?>
```

However, no errors are displayed. What really drives me nuts, is that the page itself is executed, so that I see `Hello` in my browser, but still in the console I see this notorious `500 Internal Server Error`.

PS. Apache error log contains nothing more than this:

```
[mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2400:tid 340] AH00455: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64) PHP/5.6.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 13 23:55:40.461430 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2400:tid 340] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 17 2014 12:58:29
[Thu Nov 13 23:55:40.461430 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2400:tid 340] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\Apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/Apache24'
[Thu Nov 13 23:55:40.462430 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2400:tid 340] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4552
[Thu Nov 13 23:55:40.812450 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4552:tid 228] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

Comment: Have you set a different error log for your vhost?

Comment: don't do the debug options in your script. set them at the php.ini level. It's entirely possible that PHP is getting killed BEFORE your code ever executes. setting the options in php.ini ensures they're always active. Since you see hello, php's obviously working, but may be getting killed in a shutdown sequence somewhere.

Comment: @Stony I set just one error log

Comment: I got this message too, but my PHP script works. But the performance is very very very bad.
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=26936

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurs when one of my class has lot of constants CONST defined. After I reduce CONST quantity in this class file, error disappear (perhaps reduceing them to less than 64 when apache thred limit is set so, but this is guess only). Strange but maybe helpful.